# pyCUTEst with PyTorch Optimizer

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run experiments with [PyCUTEst](https://jfowkes.github.io/pycutest/_build/html/index.html) using an optimizer from `torch.optim` . The example below is taken from [here](https://github.com/hjmshi/PyTorch-LBFGS/blob/4cd150ff0e4c4dd2183c421170eb0d3b56eb5885/examples/Other/lbfgs_tests.py#L28), where the `optim.Adam` is used instead of the `FullBatchLBFGS` which can be found [here](https://github.com/hjmshi/PyTorch-LBFGS/blob/master/functions/LBFGS.py). When running the example below the loss is not reduced. Could you please someone cast some light to find out what is wrong?

PS: The class `CUTEstProblem` can be found [here](https://github.com/hjmshi/PyTorch-LBFGS/blob/4cd150ff0e4c4dd2183c421170eb0d3b56eb5885/functions/utils.py). To install PyCUTEst you should first install CUTEst following the steps [here](https://github.com/abelsiqueira/linux-cutest).

```
import sys

import torch.optim as optim
import torch
import torch.optim
import time
import argparse
import pycutest

from utils import CUTEstProblem

max_iter = 1000
tol = 1e-3

problemName = 'ARWHEAD'
Ns = {'ARWHEAD': 1000}
print(pycutest.problem_properties('ARWHEAD'))


def _gather_flat_grad(opt: optim):
    views = []
    for group in opt.param_groups:
        for p in group['params']:
            if p.grad is None:
                view = p.data.new(p.data.numel()).zero_()
            elif p.grad.data.is_sparse:
                view = p.grad.data.to_dense().view(-1)
            else:
                view = p.grad.data.view(-1)
            views.append(view)
    return torch.cat(views, 0)


# %% Create instance of problem
sifParams = {'N': Ns[problemName]}

problem = pycutest.import_problem(problemName, sifParams=sifParams)
model = CUTEstProblem(problem)

# %% Define optimizer
lr = 1 # or smaller are used also to run the example.
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
# optimizer = FullBatchLBFGS(model.parameters(), lr=1, history_size=history_size, line_search=line_search, debug=True)

# %% Main training loop

if True:
    print('===================================================================================')
    print('Solving ' + problemName)
    print('===================================================================================')
    print('    Iter:    |     F       |    ||g||    | |x - y|/|x| |   F Evals   |    alpha    ')
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

optimizer.zero_grad()
obj = model()
obj.backward()
grad = model.grad()

x_old = model.x().clone()
x_new = x_old.clone()
f_old = obj

# main loop
for n_iter in range(max_iter):

    # define closure for line search
    def closure():
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_fn = model()
        loss_fn.backward()
        return loss_fn

    obj = optimizer.step(closure=closure)
    grad = _gather_flat_grad(optimizer)

    x_new.copy_(model.x())

    # compute quantities for checking convergence
    grad_norm = torch.norm(grad)
    x_dist = torch.norm(x_new - x_old) / torch.norm(x_old)
    f_dist = torch.abs(obj - f_old) / torch.max(torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float), torch.abs(f_old))

    # print data
    if True:
        print('  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  ' % (
            n_iter + 1, obj.item(), grad_norm.item(), x_dist.item(), lr))

    # stopping criterion
    if torch.isnan(obj) or n_iter == max_iter - 1:
        break
    elif torch.norm(grad) < tol or x_dist < 1e-6 or f_dist < 1e-7 or obj.item() == -float('inf'):
        break

    x_old.copy_(x_new)
    f_old.copy_(obj)

# print summary
print('==================================== Summary ======================================')
print('Problem:', problemName)
print('N:', problem.n)
print('Iterations:', n_iter + 1)
print('F:', obj.item())
print('||g||:', torch.norm(grad).item())
print('===================================================================================')
```

Comment: @Ivan I think I found it and it is a silly bug... I do not know if I had to answer my question or to delete it.... (Possibly I can not it is a bound)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `closure` and the `print` line....

```
import sys
import torch.optim as optim
import torch
import torch.optim
import pycutest

from utils import CUTEstProblem

max_iter = 1000
tol = 1e-6

problemName = 'ARWHEAD'
Ns = {'ARWHEAD': 1000}
print(pycutest.problem_properties('ARWHEAD'))


def _gather_flat_grad(opt: optim):
    views = []
    for group in opt.param_groups:
        for p in group['params']:
            if p.grad is None:
                view = p.data.new(p.data.numel()).zero_()
            elif p.grad.data.is_sparse:
                view = p.grad.data.to_dense().view(-1)
            else:
                view = p.grad.data.view(-1)
            views.append(view)
    return torch.cat(views, 0)


# %% Create instance of problem
sifParams = {'N': Ns[problemName]}

problem = pycutest.import_problem(problemName, sifParams=sifParams)
model = CUTEstProblem(problem)

# %% Define optimizer
lr = 0.0001
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
# optimizer = FullBatchLBFGS(model.parameters(), lr=1, history_size=history_size, line_search=line_search, debug=True)

# %% Main training loop

if True:
    print('====================================================================')
    print('Solving ' + problemName)
    print('====================================================================')
    print('    Iter:    |     F       |    ||g||    | |x - y|/|x||    alpha    ')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------')

optimizer.zero_grad()
obj = model()
obj.backward()
grad = model.grad()

x_old = model.x().clone()
x_new = x_old.clone()
f_old = obj.clone()

# main loop
for n_iter in range(max_iter):

    # define closure for line search
    def closure(backward=True):
        if backward:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_fn = model()
        if backward:
            loss_fn.backward()
        return loss_fn


    optimizer.step(closure=closure)
    obj = closure(backward=False)
    grad = _gather_flat_grad(optimizer)

    x_new.copy_(model.x())

    # compute quantities for checking convergence
    grad_norm = torch.norm(grad)
    x_dist = torch.norm(x_new - x_old) / torch.norm(x_old)
    f_dist = torch.abs(obj - f_old) / torch.max(torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float), torch.abs(f_old))

    # print data
    if True:
        # print('  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  ' % (n_iter+1, obj.item(), grad_norm.item(), x_dist.item(),  clos_evals, lr))
        print('  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  |  %.3e  ' % (
            n_iter + 1, obj.item(), grad_norm.item(), x_dist.item(), lr))

    # stopping criterion
    if torch.isnan(obj) or n_iter == max_iter - 1:
        break
    elif torch.norm(grad) < tol or x_dist < 1e-6 or f_dist < 1e-17 or obj.item() == -float('inf'):
        pass
        # break

    x_old.copy_(x_new)
    f_old.copy_(obj)

# print summary
print('==================================== Summary ======================================')
print('Problem:', problemName)
print('N:', problem.n)
print('Iterations:', n_iter + 1)
print('F:', obj.item())
print('||g||:', torch.norm(grad).item())
```

Output...

```
====================================================================
    Iter:    |     F       |    ||g||    | |x - y|/|x||    alpha    
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1.000e+00  |  8.212e+01  |  7.993e+03  |  2.528e-02  |  1.000e-04  
  2.000e+00  |  2.770e+01  |  8.341e+02  |  2.640e-03  |  1.000e-04  
  3.000e+00  |  9.771e+00  |  4.752e+02  |  1.504e-03  |  1.000e-04  
  4.000e+00  |  3.499e+00  |  2.803e+02  |  8.873e-04  |  1.000e-04  
  5.000e+00  |  1.260e+00  |  1.673e+02  |  5.297e-04  |  1.000e-04  
  6.000e+00  |  4.548e-01  |  1.003e+02  |  3.175e-04  |  1.000e-04  
  7.000e+00  |  1.647e-01  |  6.020e+01  |  1.906e-04  |  1.000e-04  
  8.000e+00  |  6.013e-02  |  3.616e+01  |  1.144e-04  |  1.000e-04  
  9.000e+00  |  2.237e-02  |  2.172e+01  |  6.874e-05  |  1.000e-04
```